# ##[error]end of the stream or a document separator is expected at line 17, column 6: - name: microServiceCompanyContainer

Tags: yaml

```
New-Item $(Agent.TempDirectory)\manifest.yaml
Set-Content $(Agent.TempDirectory)\manifest.yaml  '# Deployment
apiVersion : apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: microServicedeployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: microServicepod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: microServicepod
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: microServiceCompanyContainer
          image: microservicecontainerregistry.azurecr.io/companyapi:$(Build.BuildId)
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8000
        - name: microServiceEmployeeContainer
          image: microservicecontainerregistry.azurecr.io/employeeapi:$(Build.BuildId)
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8001
---
# Service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: microServiceservice
spec:
    type: LoadBalancer
    ports:
    - port: 8080
    selector:
        app: microServicepod'#
```

I'm trying to run this manifest.yaml file using powershell task of Azure devops Release pipeline. I'm getting the error "end of document separator expected".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.